# mapping through kinnect

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone. i am working on a robot for autonomous navigation. Currently i am able to move my robot via joy stick. now i want to get a map of surrounding using kinnect. i have ROS indego. how should i proceed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240473/mapping-through-kinnect/) by [Arpitsoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/27421/arpitsoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2016-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm also new to RoS and mapping, I was using XtionPRO but it works in the same way like kinect sensor. I recommend You to use RTAB-Map (it support assembling robot equipment) package https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap and https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros . I used it and it works well, the problem I met was transparent/absorbing surfaces but It's kinect IR problem, not package. Other package i found usable could be https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_rgbd_tools It's older than RTAB-Map and seems dead when RTAB-Map author is still active and helpful on forums ;)
I never used CCNY because i was trying to install it on kinetic and it's not compatible. 
RTAB-Map works 100% well on Ubuntu 14.04 and RoS Indigo, when using RoS Kinetic Kame i got little problems because sometimes after export package crashed, I'm not sure where is the problem because my laptop is little old Dell ;) Additionally there is a lot of tutorials and tips (from how to install RTAB-Map to how to configure Your own robot with equipment) https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki. After successful instalation i recommend You: https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Kinect-mapping . Also on http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros are a lot of informations.  
There is one more package that seems to be alive and effective: https://github.com/mp3guy/Kintinuous I was trying to use but it requires CUDA >= 7.0 which my laptop doesn't support.

Best regards.

---

Originally posted by [necro](https://answers.ros.org/users/27527/necro/) with karma: 38 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arpitsoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/27421/arpitsoni/) on 2016-08-02**:
hi.thanks for suggestion. i am following this but i am getting errors. i am posting those errors in this question itself.

**Comment by [necro](https://answers.ros.org/users/27527/necro/) on 2016-08-03**:
Have you tried building from source?
First: https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap
Next: https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros

Remember to delete: sudo apt-get remove ros-indigo-rtabmap.
On github etc. packages are for "kinetic" remember to replace all "kinetic" to "indigo".

**Comment by [necro](https://answers.ros.org/users/27527/necro/) on 2016-08-03**:
Found RTAB-Map built without its GUI library. Node rtabmapviz will not be built! That error means there is a problem with Qt or You didn't built rtabmap. You need to built rtabmap from git source and then build rtabmap_ros and put it in catkin.
http://pastebin.com/KSQHp4Bd few days ago worked,

**Comment by [Arpitsoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/27421/arpitsoni/) on 2016-08-04**:
thanks.. rtabmap is working now....
now i want to navigate my robot using the map
how should i proceed???? i have created a new question for this. plz reply there
http://answers.ros.org/question/241067/navigation/

**Comment by [necro](https://answers.ros.org/users/27527/necro/) on 2016-08-04**:
I can't help You anymore, sorry but I don't have any robot ;)
Please marked answer as solved if it helped You so others will find solution easier ;)